# How to override DisplayForm of (mixed) time Quantity

Tags: output-formatting, date-and-time, units

What's the best approach to overriding `DisplayForm` for specific types of `Quantity` eg time especially w/ mixed units?

Current is too verbose, eg:

[image]

Would rather have control as follows:

```
Quantity[MixedMagnitude@{0, 2, 3}, 
 MixedUnit@{"Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"}]
```

> 0 h 2 min 3 s

1. Would prefer either:

> :02:03

Or

> 02:03s

even if not standard, ie hide hours if zero.

2. `Quantity[2,"Minutes"]` show as `m` rather than `min` - which is used to disambiguate from unit Meters, but it's often obvious from context that it's time units.
3. Finally, to display even 0 time, which currently doesn't have a DisplayForm:

   Quantity[MixedMagnitude@{0, 0, 0}, 
        MixedUnit@{"Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"}]

What's the best approach, eg `UpSet`?

Answer (score 6):

**Code**

The function `` QuantityUnits`Private`QuantityUnitBox `` handles the display form of quantities. We modify only the definition related to mixed magnitudes and mixed units:

```
(* From a fresh kernel *)

System`Quantity;

Unprotect[QuantityUnits`Private`QuantityUnitBox];

QuantityUnits`Private`QuantityUnitBox[
    QuantityUnits`Private`QuantityUnitBox`q : 
       Quantity[
          QuantityUnits`Private`QuantityUnitBox`m_MixedMagnitude, 
          QuantityUnits`Private`QuantityUnitBox`u_MixedUnit, 
          QuantityUnits`Private`QuantityUnitBox`opts___?OptionQ
       ],
    QuantityUnits`Private`QuantityUnitBox`form_
] /; QuantityQ[QuantityUnits`Private`QuantityUnitBox`q] := With[

   {q = QuantityUnits`Private`QuantityUnitBox`q, 
    form = QuantityUnits`Private`QuantityUnitBox`form, 
    m = First@QuantityUnits`Private`QuantityUnitBox`m, 
    u = First@QuantityUnits`Private`QuantityUnitBox`u},

    If[u === {"Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"} || u === {"Minutes", "Seconds"},
       myQuantityDisplay[m, u],
       QuantityUnits`Private`ToMixedUnitQuantityTemplateBox[q, form]
    ]

];

Protect[QuantityUnits`Private`QuantityUnitBox];
```

Compared to the original version, we just added an `If` statement with a test on the form of the mixed units. The function `myQuantityDisplay` will fire for OP's requirements only, otherwise the standard display will be kept.

(To change the display of any time quantities, probably `UnitDimensions` and `TimeUnit` could be used in some way for the test.)

We are left with the definition of `myQuantityDisplay`

```
myQuantityDisplay[{m_, s_}, {"Minutes", "Seconds"}] := 
    IntegerString[m, 10, 2] <> ":" <> IntegerString[s, 10, 2] <> "s";

myQuantityDisplay[{0, m_, s_}, {"Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"}] := 
    IntegerString[m, 10, 2] <> ":" <> IntegerString[s, 10, 2] <> "s";

myQuantityDisplay[{h_, m_, s_}, {"Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"}] := 
    IntegerString[h, 10, 2] <> ":" <> IntegerString[m, 10, 2] <> ":" <> 
    IntegerString[s, 10, 2] <> "s";
```

The above modification only affects the display form, so that we can still perform any operation or standard evaluation on mixed quantites. Also, as mentioned, only the mixed units specifications given in the `If` statement are concerned.

(See *Comments* below for point 3 of OP's question.)

**A few examples**

*a) Modified display*

```
Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{1, 2, 3}], MixedUnit[{"Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"}]]
% // FullForm
```

[image]

*b) Standard display*

```
Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{14, 35}], MixedUnit[{"Hours", "Minutes"}]]
```

[image]

*c) Arithmetic operations*

```
q = Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{14, 35}], MixedUnit[{"Minutes", "Seconds"}]]
3 q
```

[image]

**Comments**

The definitions of the function `` QuantityUnits`Private`QuantityUnitBox `` can be accessed with `PrintDefinitions`. Otherwise, from the `PrintDefinitions` of `Quantity`, one has to search for the function `` QuantityUnits`QuantityBox `` in

```
MakeBoxes[x : Quantity[_, u_?QuantityUnits`Private`LooksLikeAUnitQ, ___], fmt_] ...
```

and from its definitions look at the second cell.

Among all the definitions of `` QuantityUnits`Private`QuantityUnitBox ``, we can see one responsible for the format of mixed quantities (modified above), and one that concerns the display (or lack of it) for repeated zeros in the mixed magnitude. So to achieve point 3 of OP's question, simply do

```
QuantityUnits`Private`$ShowZero = True;
```

Note that the function `myQuantityDisplay` should have definitions that are within the scope of `MakeBoxes` (as we can see from above). I think we can get more fancy outputs than the one I gave by tweaking instead the functions used by `` QuantityUnits`Private`ToMixedUnitQuantityTemplateBox ``, though this requires more spelunking.

Comment: Xavier, thank you for this info, this more involved than I thought it would be.  Does every expression with a `DisplayForm` have its own `_UnitBox`?

Answer (score 4):

This might give you a start. You will need to [`Unprotect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unprotect.html) [`MixedMagnitude`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MixedMagnitude.html) and [`MixedUnit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MixedUnit.html), so the usual caveats apply.

```
Unprotect[MixedMagnitude, MixedUnit];

Quantity[HoldPattern@MixedMagnitude[x_List], 
  MixedUnit[{"Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"}]] ^:= 
 StringRiffle[
  IntegerString[#, 10, 2] & /@ If[x[[1]] == 0, Rest[x], x], ":"]

Quantity[MixedMagnitude@{0, 2, 3}, 
 MixedUnit@{"Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"}]
(* "02:03" *)

Quantity[MixedMagnitude@{10, 20, 30}, 
 MixedUnit@{"Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"}]
(* "10:20:30" *)
```